# Assignment loop fails: "undefined variable"

Tags: javascript

```
var xyz, i, tx = {}
// Doesn't work: var xyz, i, tx = {}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Doesn't work: window.xyz, window.i, window.tx
    xyz[i].tx = 5
    // Doesn't work: xyz[i]["tx"] = 5
}

alert(xyz);
```

Returns `TypeError: xyz is undefined`.

I defined variables, tries forced scoping, tried two different ways to call the array. I don't get it. How can I get it to write variables in the loop.

Comment: Your xyz is undefined yet you try to access its elements from the first through the fifth. You should at least initialize it to an array.

Comment: declare `xyz` as `var xyz = []`

Comment: You have to declare it like `var xyz=[], i=0, tx = {};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the array already contains an item. If not, just create one. You probably don't need any other variables declared at the beginning.

```
var xyz = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // do this if you are not changing the objects a getting to this point a second time
    xyz[i] = {tx: 5};
}
alert(xyz);
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/mtr6hdty/2/

Depending on what you want to do in the for loop you can also use the shorthand version from [Ele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715121/ele)

Comment: Thats the one, took some implementing.

Comment: Thats what you were looking for you mean?

Comment: @mplungjan Fine if he does not modify the xyz array somewhere else and comes back to that point ....

Comment: @lightstalker89 Yes. I forgot to assign the data, was a tad frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

According to your intention to create an object for each index, you can initialize the array `xyz` and use the function `push` to add new elements.

```js
var xyz = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) xyz.push({'tx': 5});
console.log(xyz);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another straightforward approach is create your array using the class `Array`along with the function `from`.

```js
var xyz = Array.from({length: 5}, (x) => ({'tx': 5}));
console.log(xyz);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

## Resource

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: @mplungjan the problem with that approach is the same reference in every index.

Comment: @mplungjan when you use `fill({tx: 5})` you're sharing the same reference for every index, therefore, a modification i.e `xyz[0].tx = 6` will modify the other indexes.

Comment: Ah - that is interesting

Comment: @mplungjan JS is amazing hehehe